# LINK2019 unresolved external symbol _time64

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio

foo.exe depends on bar.lib

source.c in bar.lib:

```
#include <time.h>
void func()
{
    time_t now = time(NULL);
    ... // use 'now'
}
```

Bar.lib can be generated. However, foo.exe's linking process will report an error:

```
LINK2019
unresolved external symbol '_time64' referenced in function 'time'. 
foo
bar.lib(source.obj)
```

What may cause this?

Comment: What happens if you use `time_t now = time(NULL);` directly in foo.c and you remove `time_t now = time(NULL);` from source.c? Just to see if it builds. BTW bar.lib could be built even with `int DoesnNotExist(); ... int x = DoesNotExist() ;`, but linking inorder to build a .exe would fail

Comment: "What happens if you use time_t now = time(NULL); directly in foo.c and you remove time_t now = time(NULL); from source.c? "
foo.exe reports LINK2019 in its own obj, that is strange...

Comment: Show the full verbatim error log. BTW foo.exe cannot report anything because it cannot even been built.

Comment: LINK2019
unresolved external symbol '_time64' referenced in function 'time'. 
foo
foo.obj

Comment: "foo.exe" has an soure file named "foo.c", so it reports in foo.obj.

Comment: Try to build a Hello World program from scratch that does just a `time_t now = time(NULL);` and see if that works

Comment: I have tried in another  solution but the same env. It works. It may be caused by some link option in the project?

Comment: Yes, it's probably somewhere in the link options.